# ip routing on centos

Tags: centos, routing

My server has two network interfaces. 
I set ip address as `10.254.1.5/16` and `172.16.20.40/16` and default gateway `10.254.1.1/16`.

`172.16.0.0` network between the two devices. This network is not attached to the `10.254.0.0` network.

we use local DNS. The DNS servers IP addresses are `172.16.1.1` and `172.16.1.2`.

I get the error message "unknown host" when ping to `google.com`".

I want the DNS request to route via the default gateway ( `172.16.1.1` and `172.16.1.2` to `10.254.1.1`)

What can I do? Server OS is CentOS 6.5.

```
route table :
172.16.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth3
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth2
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 eth3
10.254.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth2
default         10.254.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
```

first interface configuration

```
DEVICE=eth2
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=b864bcfb-3ac2-4ba8-9c19-9ec24cf7807c
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.254.1.5
PREFIX=16
GATEWAY=10.254.1.1
DNS1=172.16.1.1
DNS2=172.16.1.2
DOMAIN=stv.local
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth2"
HWADDR=E4:1F:13:DA:2B:32
```

second interface configuration

```
DEVICE=eth3
HWADDR=E4:1F:13:DA:2B:36
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=172.16.20.40
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
NETWORK=172.16.0.0
UUID=7b447b6e-6564-468b-a95c-df1cc34121c0
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
```

and

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 172.16.1.1
nameserver 172.16.1.2
```

Comment: I've flagged this for moderator attention - This question might belong on Superuser, but not Serverfault as it is of a basic nature.  Worse, the details and config information need to be teased out before a meaningful answer can be given as there are errors in the assumptions - eg 172.x is not a /8

Answer (score 0):

On the client you are trying to ping Google from, can you not add 172.16.1.1 172.16.1.2 to the  /etc/resolv.conf file in this format:

```
nameserver 172.16.1.1
nameserver 172.16.1.2
```

Sorry, question is a bit unclear.

Routing can be done through IPtables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i YOURINTERFACE --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.254.1.1:53
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d 10.254.1.1 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```